# creating a makfile to run simple python program on different files

Tags: python, makefile

I have a python file that needs to import 5 other python modules in order to run.
The main program is very simple and short because it uses the classes defined in the 5 import files. Now I have to submit a make file that responds to several commands. All the commands run the main program on different files and are instructed to be as follows;  "make cat-dictionary" should display the file "dictionary" that the program will be run on.....while "make run-dictionary" will execute the python program on "dictionary". I found a ton of help on how to use make file  with C code that needs compiling. But I am confused how to make sure my make commands allow the main python program to import the 5 modules it needs before executing it? Do I have to use a command that prepares the modules or will my python program just import them automatically if they are there.

Comment: The make commands have nothing to do with python's imports. You write `import module1, module2, ..., module5` in your python file, and use the make file only to start your program. (If you have an `import` statement like that, then yes, your program will import the modules "automatically" when it starts.)

Comment: Ok thank you thats what I was wondering I've never made one before.

Answer (score 0):

## Packaging Python program via `setup.py`

To make Python code easily installable, you shall use `setup.py`, which will allow creation of a package.

## Python `make` via `doit`

If you really need to run multiple dependent tasks and search for Python alternative to Makefile, check [`doit`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/doit/0.29.0) package.

Note, that for completing a python program `doit` is not needed.